# Check if item exists in an NSMutableArray

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsmutablearray

I've got an NSMutableArray that holds custom objects. An example of its contents are as follows:

```
2013-03-14 20:06:23.895 MyMusicLibrary[1667:c07] myLibrary: (
    {
    artist = "Green Day";
    id = 1421768;
    name = "American Idiot";
    releasedate = "21 Sep 2004";
    runningtime = "57.53";
    tracks = "1: American Idiot\n2: Jesus of Suburbia\n3: Holiday/Boulevard Of Broken Dreams\n4: Are We The Waiting/St. Jimmy\n5: Give Me Novacaine/She's A Rebel\n6: Extraordinary Girl/Letterbomb\n7: Wake Me Up When September Ends\n8: Homecoming\n9: Whatsername\n";
    trackscount = 9;
    type = 1;
},
    {
    artist = Bastille;
    id = 309124896;
    name = "Bad Blood";
    releasedate = "1 Mar 2013";
    runningtime = "43.98";
    tracks = "1: Pompeii\n2: Things We Lost in the Fire\n3: Bad Blood\n4: Overjoyed\n5: These Streets\n6: Weight of Living, Pt. II\n7: Icarus\n8: Oblivion\n9: Flaws\n10: Daniel in the Den\n11: Laura Palmer\n12: Get Home\n13: Weight of Living, Pt. I\n";
    trackscount = 13;
    type = 1;
},
    {
    artist = "Lacuna Coil";
    id = 2025689;
    name = Comalies;
    releasedate = "16 Oct 2012";
    runningtime = "51.75";
    tracks = "1: Swamped\n2: Heaven's a Lie\n3: Daylight Dancer\n4: Humane\n5: Self Deception\n6: Aeon\n7: Tight Rope\n8: The Ghost Woman and the Hunter\n9: Unspoken\n10: Entwined\n11: The Prophet Said\n12: Angels Punishment\n13: Comalies\n";
    trackscount = 13;
    type = 1;
}
)
```

How would I loop through the array, to check if an ID already existed?

Comment: Also, this is neither iPhone- nor Xcode-specific. I hate tag abuse!

Comment: what's up with the downvotes? The dude has a worthy question, whether or not tags were "abused". We were all beginners once, people. No need for snarky comments either, he explicitly asked how to loop the array, he doesn't need to be told to use a loop.

Comment: @JustinAmberson even though I did not downvote, I think it is perfectly fine for anyone to chose if he thinks that a question `does not show any research effort` etc.. No need to tell us if you are of a different opinion. Just express that opinion by tapping on the up-arrow.

Comment: @JustinAmberson To give some reasoning regarding my downvote and to defend myself against you accusing me of stuff I didn't do: "We were all beginners once, people" - Surely I was, and that's why I generated enormous amounts of hits to Google's servers. I didn't have to ask questions like this on Stack Overflow.

Comment: I'm sorry if you think it's a stupid question. I'm really new to Objective-C, and I'm used to the .NET way of doing things such as using Array.Length. I can assure you I do use Google extensively while writing code, and I did so for this query. I just didn't find anything that made a lot of sense to me, so I decided to ask here. I usually find StackOverflow full of people who are more than willing to lend a hand, even when they think the question asked was very simple. I'm not sure why this question seems to have provoked such disgust!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't state what objects are in your array. The following should work in general:

```
NSMutableArray *array = ... // the array with the objects
id keyToFind = ... // the key to locate
for (id object in array) {
    id key = [object valueForKey:@"id"];
    if ([key isEqual:keyToFind]) {
        // found
    }
}
```

The use of each `id` can be replaced with more specific classes as needed.

Answer (score 1):

Loop through the array and check in each iteration whether the ID is the current one. If it is, the ID exists. If not, the ID does not exist in the array.

Answer (score 0):

With a `for` loop

```
NSInteger idToCheck = 12345;
for (MyObject *obj in myArray){
    if (obj.id == idToCheck) {
        //do something here
    }
}
```